# What's faster? Searching for shortest path in a matrix or a list?

Tags: list, graph, path, performance, shortest

I have to store some cities and the distances between some of them and then search for the shortest path. The cities and the distances are read from a file.
I started with doing a matrix but saw that it took too much space(more than double) so I changed to a list. Each list item stores 3 things: point1, point2 and the distance between them.

So for example I have this file:

> Athens Stockholm 34
>   Stockholm Prague 23

which when I read is stored in the array as this:

```
          _____0______ ______1______
point1   | Athens     | Stockholm   |
point2   | Stockholm  | Prague      |
distance | 34         | 23          |
          ------------ -------------
```

Then I got some doubts.. This surely saves space but is it going to take more time to go through? The list is an array but the connections(edges) are placed in an arbitrary way and that's why I started thinking that it may take more time than if I used a matrix.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into the adjacency-list representation of graphs, which is a modified version of your second idea that's best suited for shortest path problems.  The idea is to have a table of nodes where for each node you store a list of outgoing edges from that node.  This allows you to iterate over all the edges leaving a node in time proportional to the number of edges you have leaving a node, not the total number of edges in the graph (as you have in both the matrix and list versions suggested above).  For this reason, most fast algorithms for doing graph searches use adjacency lists.

Hope his helps!

Comment: I tryied to implement that but I ran into a problem: Where will the distance be stored? I am not sure that it is even possible.

Comment: You would probably store the distances in the edges, since whenever you follow an edge you need to know how long it is.

Comment: @templatetypedef: Is it possible to use adjacency lists with prim's algorithm? And what about Edmond's Blossom algorithm? Do you know a shortcut?

Comment: The only implementations I've ever seen use adjacency lists, though that may ge because I wrote them. :-). I know of very few graph algorithms for which an adjacency matrix is the best representation, and in fact I'm going to go ask if anyone knows of any.

Comment: @templatetypedef: Could you explain why the triangle inequality doesn't apply to roundtrips? I am not sure I understand.

Comment: @epitaph the algorithm has nothing to do with the way your data is stored. You can use any algorithm in any kind of data structure.

Answer (score 2):

Separate the names from the distances. Create a list that just contains city names.

```
          _____0______ ______1______ ______2______ 
city     | Athens     | Stockholm   | Prague      |
          ------------ ------------- -------------
```

Then create the matrix separately

```
     __0__ __1__ __2__ 
 0  | 0   | 34  | 0   |
     ----- ----- -----
 1  | 34  | 0   | 23  |
     ----- ----- -----
 2  | 0   | 23  | 0   |
     ----- ----- -----
```

If you want to search, say, a route from Prague to Athens, then you start by finding where Prague and Athens are in the list...

- Prague: 2
- Athens: 0

Then you search through the matrix for your path.

- (2,1,23) -> (1,0,34)

Finally, you translate to cities using your list

- (Prague, Stockholm, 23) ->
  (Stockholm, Athens, 34)

Answer (score 1):

I think that adjecency lists here are surely the best option here. The're later very useful when it comes to algorithms like D/BFS or Dijkstra.

If you don't know how to keep both towns and distances just use some structure to keep them both together. If you could use numbered indexed towns you would use just a simple pair structure (also the easiest implementation would be n STL vectors of pair.

Of course if you don't want to use STL you should try implementing own lists of structures with pointers you would want to use.

Comment: But why are adjecency lists better? From what point of view? Lists seem slower to go through than matrices.

Comment: Becouse in a list you have exactly that many elements as you have possible paths, on matrix you need to check if a path exists to any element and then you can proceed. So concluding the time is the same only in case that graph is full (you have routes to each other town), it's not often. In normal case when using you just don't have to perform n checks, just exactly as many as you need to check.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks just fine.

To relax your mind, remember that parsing a single list/array will always be be faster and more resource friendly than working with two (or more) lists when you practically just need to look up a single line/entry of predefined data.

I tend to disagree with some of the other answers here, since I do not see any need to complicate things. Looking up several data-cells and the additional need to be combine those data-cells to produce a resulting data set (as some answers proposed), takes more steps than doing a simple one-time run over a list to fetch a line of data. You would merely risk losing CPU cycles and memory resources for functions that lookup and combine distributed data-cells across several lists, while the data you currently use already is combined as a collection of perfect results.

Simpler said: doing a simple run-down on the list/array you currently have is hard to beat when it comes to speed.